# Magento 2 - Assign drop down attribute value to product programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productID = 12; // Product ID

$option_label = 'XL'; // atttribute option label

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID);

$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size'); // Get attribute 
details by code 

if ($attribute->usesSource()) {

    $option_id = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($option_label); // Get Option id using option label

}

$product->setSize($option_id);

$product->save();
```

Comment: yes, you are using correct method. For drop down attribute we need to first fetch the option id using the label and then use that id to assign the value to the product. Your code should work but if it is not working then you can check your attribute's scope in admin. I also faced the same issue once and setting the scope as global for the attirbute, the above code worked. Earlier the attribute's scope was set to store view.